# In a function, what's the difference between an inlined return type and the return type defined in a separate type definition?

Tags: typescript, async-await, type-definition

I'm getting an inconsistent behaviour when I inline the return value type of a function and if I define it in a separate type definition.

For example:

```js
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

type Fooer = () => Foo;

const foo1: Fooer = () => { // It knows `.bar` should be a string
    return {
        bar: 123,
    };
}

// Return type set in a separate type definition
const foo2: Fooer = () => {
    return {
        foo: 123, // It doesn't complain about additional properties
        bar: "zzz",
    };
}

// Inline (repeated) return type
const foo3: Fooer = (): Foo => {
    return {
        foo: 123, // And now it does...
        bar: "zzz",
    };
}
```

[Try it on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Fooer%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20Foo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo1%3A%20Fooer%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20It%20knows%20%60.bar%60%20should%20be%20a%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20123%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo2%3A%20Fooer%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20123%2C%20%2F%2F%20It%20doesn't%20complain%20about%20additional%20properties%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%22zzz%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo3%3A%20Fooer%20%3D%20()%3A%20Foo%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20123%2C%20%2F%2F%20And%20now%20it%20does...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%22zzz%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

I'd expect `foo2` and `foo3` to have the same behaviour (personally I expect both to show the same error, or at least to be consistent).

What am I missing here? What's the difference between both approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is a result of TypeScript's 'duck typing'.  Basically, the fact that the return type in foo2 has a `bar` field that is a string means that the function has a signature `() => Promise<{foo: number, bar: string}>`, which can be assigned to the `foo2` variable of type `Fooer` due to duck typing.

However, in foo3, you can think of the type checking as being applied directly on the return type instead of on the entire function.  As a result you see the error `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type 'Foo'.` since the type checking is performed on the object literal, which has the additional requirement that it can't specify unknown properties when you give it an explicit type.

Comment: And is there a way for me to ensure a stricter check based on the return type defined in `Fooer` (or, is there a way to make `foo2` trigger an error)?

Comment: The way to make foo2 trigger an error is to essentially just use foo3.  You could also explicitly create a variable inside the body of foo2 with the type `Foo` which you assign an object literal to.  That variable would then be returned.  That way, you will see a type error when you assign the object literal to that variable.

Comment: I see. : / This forces developers to import both `Fooer` and `Foo` (in my real case they are in a separate module and are reused in several places, I was trying to make it as simple as possible for developers to get proper type check). Thank you very much for your help! : )

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how TypeScript treats type literals, and not with whether a function is async or not — if these were regular functions the behavior would be the same.

In general, TypeScript allows excess properties to exist in objects. If an object has all its required properties, the rest doesn't matter. The exceptions are pretty much what you discovered: type literals and explicitly defined return types.

Comment: Interesting. But it still feels like an undesired behaviour to me. : (

Is there a way to ensure the return type in `Fooer` without allowing additional parameters? And thanks for the reply, btw. : )